# Switching Scenes Keeping State JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, desktop-application, scene

I created this method to help with scene switching, but in this case, if I wanted to make a back button, the old scene status is lost because it will be reloaded, I would like to know a way to do something like we have in **Android**, the "**stacking**" of Activitys, in this case, scenes.

```
public void changeStage(Control event, String title, String url){
       try {           
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/gro/admin/java/" + url));
        Stage stage = (Stage) event.getScene().getWindow();
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        stage.setTitle(title);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setMaximized(false); 
        stage.setMaximized(true); 

        } catch (IOException ex) {
           log("Switch error", ex);

        } 
}
```

Comment: You could keep a `Map<String, Scene>` mapping from the url to the scene and check this map before creating the new scene. If you create a new scene, store it in the map...

Comment: @fabian Could you show me an example, if you have some tutorial link or github I thank you very much